# How to properly pass immutablejs object in flux

Tags: javascript, immutability, reactjs-flux, immutable.js

I am using react+flux in an application. I am trying to use immutable js to speed up the rendering process as everytime I make any small change to the state, react tries to reconcile all DOMs (which is quite slow).

The problem I am encountering is that inside my store.js, I can convert my state into an immutable Map object. However, as soon as this object is passed to the app, it is no longer recognised as Map object, but just a normal object. This means I cannot use any set or get functions that come with Map object

This is what I have so far:

Store.js

```
var Immutable = require("immutable");

var Store = function(){   
    var jsState = { object1 : "state of object 1", 
                    object2 : "state of object 2"}
    this.globalState = Immutable.fromJS(globalState);

    this._getGlobalState = function(){
        //console will log: Map { size=2,  _root=ArrayMapNode,  __altered=false,  more...}
        //this.globalState.get("object1"); will work
        console.log(this.globalState); 
        return this.globalState;
    }
}
```

App.js

```
var Store = require("./Store.js");
var Map = require("immutable").Map

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return ({});
    },
    componentWillMount: function()
        this._getStateFromStore(); //will get the immutable state from the store
    },
    _getStateFromStore: function()
    {
        return this.setState(Store._getGlobalState());
    },
    render: function(){
        //this will return Object { size=2,  _root=ArrayMapNode,  __altered=false,  more...}
        //this.state.get("object1") will NOT work
        console.log(this.state);
        return <div>This is in App</div>
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I missing any modules in any of the files? Many thanks!

Comment: It will be faster to create the `Immutable.Map` directly: `var jsState = Immutable.Map({ object1 : "state of object 1", 
                    object2 : "state of object 2"})` instead of using `fromJS`. Also, you'll want to have a `componentShouldUpdate` method to take advantage of using Immutable. Check out the [`PureRenderMixin`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) as an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't actually force the `State` object to be an Immutable object. Rather, you have to store Immutable objects within your state.

So, you'll want to do something like:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return ({
    data: Immutable.Map({})
  });
},

...
_getStateFromStore: function()
{
  return this.setState({
    data: Store._getGlobalState()
  });
},
```

[Facebook has a good example repo on this subject.](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state)